# Converting Address List to Hash 160

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin

I have a list of addresses and I want to print it in RIPEMD160 format. The output is not what I expected, I want to output in hexadecimal format.

```
import base58

with open('addresses.txt', 'r') as f:
    for adr58 in f:
        adr160 = base58.b58decode_check(adr58)
        print (adr160)
```

**PRINT:**

```
b'\x00\x0c\xc3\xfeew\x0f\xe2\xc08#\xfe&.\xe7my\x91\xb5\xe4\x1f'
b'\x00\x0c\xc4\x02&\xdf &\xa1N+U\xaf>\xafo*=B\xd2\n'
```

**What I want to see is output:**

```
0CC3FE65770FE2C03823FE262EE76D7991B5E41F
0CC40226DF2026A14E2B55AF3EAF6F2A3D42D20A
```

**addresses.txt**

```
12AVuBktk7GXirPsNS5DZrFnbjFukLR2Qb
12AVvCskys7KNAxErcouKmrSqMB9xbKGxN
```

Comment: Provide the content of `addresses.txt`

Comment: `print(adr160.hex())` ?